# How can I proper validate the phone number field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm stuck at a point. I need to validate a phone number by preventing below formats. For now I've applied the 10 digits validation but below formats are not correct.

```
0000000000
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
4444444444
5555555555
6666666666
7777777777
8888888888
9999999999
```

also I need to avoid those numbers which are starting with either `1` or `0`. Like validation should avoid below formats as well.

```
1xxxxxxxxx
0xxxxxxxxx
```

Can anyone suggest me a way of doing that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try this.

```
^(?!(\d)\1{9}$)[2-9]\d{9}$
```

- `(?!(.)\1{9}$)` won't be the same digit which repeats exactly 10 times.
- `[2-9]` must starts with 2 or 3 or upto 9.
- `\d{9}` any 9 digits.
- `$` line end.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vY2mK9/1)

**or**

```
^([2-9])(?!\1{9}$)\d{9}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vY2mK9/2)

Comment: Perfect. Simplest solution ever. :-)

Comment: Nitpicking : maybe just replace the dot with a \d ? Just seems more in context this way.

Comment: @Pif added much more efficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below one works as well

```js
 var rex = /^[01].{9}|(.)\1{9}$/;
return !rex.test(phone)
```